# How to setup and access session of Shopify using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, express, session, shopify

Is this the correct way to setup a shop with `SQLiteSessionStorage`?

```
const storage = new SQLiteSessionStorage(DB_PATH)
const shopify = shopifyApp({
  api: {
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    restResources,
    billing: undefined, // or replace with billingConfig above to enable example billing
    scopes: ['write_products', 'read_locales'],
  },
  auth: {
    path: '/api/auth',
    callbackPath: '/api/auth/callback',
  },
  webhooks: {
    path: '/api/webhooks',
  },
  sessionStorage: storage,

});
export default shopify;
```

If so, how can I access this session from anywhere in my app?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. like this:

shopify.js (assuming you use the shopifyApp and SQLite as db):

```
import { shopifyApp } from "@shopify/shopify-app-express";
import { SQLiteSessionStorage } from "@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-sqlite";

const dbFile = join(process.cwd(), "database.sqlite");
const sessionDb = new SQLiteSessionStorage(dbFile);

const shopify = shopifyApp({
    [...]
    sessionStorage: sessionDb,
});
```

folder/your.function.js:

```
import shopify from "../shopify.js";

const sessionId = await shopify.api.session.getOfflineId('myshop.shopify.com');
const session = await shopify.config.sessionStorage.loadSession(sessionId);
const restClient = new shopify.api.clients.Rest({ session });
```

Comment: This only get the session id, but how to get the actual session from the storage?

Comment: @SamTest, pardon, my bad, updated the answer